# Is it possible to detect when a new Fragment appears in an app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on some testing tools and need to be able to determine when the UI of my app under test changes. If an app just uses Activities, I can use the Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor to detect when a new Activity is displayed. Is there anything analogous for Fragments?

It looks like `FragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener` will let me detect *some* Fragment changes (when the old Fragment is pushed onto the back stack?) but will probably not fire if the new Fragment is shown without adding anything to the back stack.

Any pointers for how to detect when a new Fragment is displayed?

Thanks!